# TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ciphersuite in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-4.5

I want to use this specific cipher suite: `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` (or perhaps `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` but prefferd would be the first) in C#, unfortunately .net does not support this. I've seen many questions about PSK, or the `SslStream` class of .net but all are dated, most are at least 3 years old.

I want my embedded devices to communicate to a server using TLS over TCP, It is not a website it's simply any kind of data which is send over this connection. I also do not have direct access to the TCP sockets and listeners.

so I have 3 questions regarding this:

> 1. Is this still the case in .net 4.5? (I've looked far and wide and it seems it is).
> 2. Is there an easy to use library for C# (preferably free) which supports either of the 2 cipher suites?
> 3. Can I create the cipher suite my self and add it to the .net version of TLS?

To summ up: 
Cipher suite = `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`
TLS version = `1.2`
.net version = `4.5`
I am looking for something that can do the server side of TLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working implementation of bounty castle, this has a mockPSKServer and client and supports the desired cipher suite.

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp